# Update content of a buffer in side window when a custom mode is on

Tags: buffers, major-mode

I have following code which is supposed to clear existing content in a buffer and write new one.

```lisp
(defun display-file-dir (path)
  (text-mode) 
  (if buffer-read-only
    (read-only-mode))
  (erase-buffer)
  (dolist (entry (get-files-and-directories path))
      (insert entry "\n"))
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (navigator-mode)
  (setq navigator-breadcrumb path))
```

When I run the code, Emacs complains that the buffer is in read only mode.
How do it toggle the read only mode given a buffer is loaded in a side window and has custom major mode enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way of temporary inhibiting read only mode programmatically is by setting `inhibit-read-only` to t with `let`:

```lisp
(let ((inhibit-read-only t))
  (erase-buffer)
  ;; do your things
  ) ; end of read only
```